# unexpectedly found nil while wrapping in swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

i am getting this error

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

this is my code where i get the error.

```
if (method == .POST) {
            Alamofire.request(uri, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

                    switch response.result
                    {
                    case .success(let value):
//                        let json = JSON(value)

                         let SDNetworkResponseValue =
                            self.prepareResponseObject(success: response.result.isSuccess, withData: value as Any, andError: ((response.result.error! as NSError)))
                        completionHandler(SDNetworkResponseValue)

                    case .failure(let error):
                        let SDNetworkResponseValue = self.prepareResponseObject(success: response.result.isSuccess, withData: response.result.value as Any , andError: (error as NSError))
                        completionHandler(SDNetworkResponseValue)


                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This error occurs when you force unwrap an optional value is nil.

I see you are force unwrapping the response.result.error! while this error can be nil. You should check if this error is nil or not.

Comment: On which line you got the error ??

Comment: @iOS.Wolf, here i am getting errors --- let SDNetworkResponseValue =
                            self.prepareResponseObject(success: response.result.isSuccess, withData: value as Any, andError: ((response.result.error! as NSError)))
                        completionHandler(SDNetworkResponseValue)

Comment: @iOS.Wolf, i don't know buddy how can i fix this pls help me out

Comment: Can you show your `prepareResponseObject()` method code ??

Comment: @Milander i check error and its nil, what shall i supposed  to do

Answer (score 3):

In the `.success` case the `error` of the `result` is always `nil`, unwrapping `response.result.error!` crashes reliably.

I assume that the `andError` parameter is an optional type, so write

```
self.prepareResponseObject(success: response.result.isSuccess, withData: value as Any, andError: nil)
```

Comment: @ vadian, after adding these lines of code i got the error ;

Comment: @ vadian error --Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSError'

Comment: @ vadian what is supposed to be pls help me out

Comment: The method `prepareResponseObject` makes no sense if you have to return a non-optional `NSError`,  on success there is no error. By the way in Swift you should use only `Error`

Comment: @ vadian i am not getting your point can you tell me how i can fix this?

Comment: You have to change the declaration of `prepareResponseObject` to make the `andError` parameter optional.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because you used an implicitly unwrapped optional (using `!`) with `response.result`. Whenever you use this operator on a `nil` value, a crash occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot run your code as you are using third parties
But try this :-

```
 self.prepareResponseObject(success: response.result.isSuccess, withData: value as Any, andError: ((response.result.error as? NSError ?? NSError.init(domain: "Error", code: 400, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:"Something went wrong"])))
```